# django application field loaded from already created database and not initialized from the django code

Tags: python, django

I see that you can initialize a new field type to be created in a new database from the django application code inside of models.py.

Something like this:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
```

If I already have a database created, and that database is already connected to my django instance running ... and lets say I have a table called product_colors that has the following columns

```
coolerless_print boolean not null
print_color varchar(20)
id bigserial not null
```

How do I load these already created columns into my newly created app? Does Djangos, i dont know the right terminology here, field initiation process have equivalencies for all possible sql data types, exceptions (not null), etc? Is there an easy way to say - load this table and all columns?

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/tutorial02/

Comment: When you run `python manage.py makemigrations and python manage.py migrate` Django would automatically create the models for you. In your case, it would automatically create a `YOURAPPNAME_question` table in your database.

Comment: i guess what im saying is, if i already have a database loaded with data and I just want to connect my app in django to it - not initialize a new database or create new columns ... how does one do that? @Paolo

Comment: If that's the case, you'll make use of Django's `inspectdb`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're planning to connect your Django app to an existing database, then you're probably going to use

```
python manage.py inspectdb
```

Full explanation can be found here. [Integrating Django with a legacy database.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/legacy-databases/)

Comment: Happy to help, please don't forget to mark as correct answer to help other people searching about the same problem too.